# (jquery + angular2) get value from input

Tags: jquery, angular2

Не могу отследить изменения в:

```
<input type="text" id="birthday" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="user.birthday" ngControl="birthday">
```

при задания значения помощью

```
jQuery('#birthday').val('asdasd');
```

Comment: Странная идея менять значение поля ввода в ангуляре через jquery.

Comment: вызовите `change` событие вручную `jQuery('#birthday').val('asdasd').change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.birthday" ngControl="birthday">
    </div>
</div>
```

Контролер:

```
declare let jQuery: any;

export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit{
    private user = {};
}

ngOnInit() {
    let self = this;

    jQuery('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked",
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    }).on('change', function(e) {
         let input = jQuery(this).children('input');
         self.user[input.attr( 'ngcontrol' )] = input.val();
    });
}
```

Comment: Суть задачи, подключения bootstrap datepicker, а не ng2-bootstrap datepicker